# Convert UTC Timestamp to a normal date & timr

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have a PostgreSql which creates a timestamp with timezone for every row. But now when i try to printout this timestamp I get the following : 
"2013-03-06 00:00:00+01:00"

Firstly why says it 00:00:00 ?

Secondly how could I convert it to such a thing:

06.03.2013 07:10:13

Or

For Example : "12 sec ago", "1 day and a hour ago"

Thank you
Marvin

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) of the python module. From that module you can convert string to date and format that date.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('06.03.2013 07:10:13', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S%Z')
'2013-06-03 07:10:13'
```

Answer (score 1):

You got `00:00:00` as time part probably because somebody inserted just date without time part. See for results of:

```
select current_date, current_timestamp;
```

you will get:

```
"2013-03-07";"2013-03-07 08:31:59.098661+01"
```

When you INSERT or UPDATE timestamp column with just date then time part will be cut to `00:00:00`. You should use `current_timestamp` if you want date , time and time zone.

Converting such date for string can be done on both server and client side. There are many [PostgreSQL datetime functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), [PostgreSQL format functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) that can be used as well as Python functions.

With:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'DD.MM.YY HH12:MI:SS')
```

you will get something like:

```
"07.03.13 08:40:50"
```

Lafada answer covers Python formating of datetime objects.

When you want to show difference between now and some datetime you can use PostgreSQL `age()` function:

```
select age(timestamp '2003-03-01');
```

result:

```
"10 years 6 days"
```

Of course Python also can show difference between timestamps:

```
import datetime
dt_old = datetime.datetime.strptime('2001-12-31 22:33:44', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dt_diff = (datetime.datetime.today() - dt_old)
print(dt_diff)
```

my result:

```
4083 days, 10:16:14.140000
```

Comment: Thank you for your really great answer :) ..i doesn't insert something in the timestamp column i configured it like this `addedat TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()`

Comment: PostgreSQL `now()` function returns date with time, but in your declaration it will be used only if somebody do not set value for this column in INSERT statement. You must search for INSERTs in your application. Also it is better to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of PostgreSQL: specific `now()` -- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will work with other databases I know.